# Code working in console but not working in extension script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have this `querySelector` call working in the console but not working in the script of the extension. To be precise it works if I remove a part of the selector, but as it is right now, it returns `null`.

I tried to load the selector after the DOM is loaded and even after a timeout of 10 seconds, same result.

I don't think the actual piece of code will help you, but if it gives you any clue, here you have it.

```js
document.querySelector("body > sn-workspace-layout > sn-workspace-main > sn-workspace-primary-content > sn-ux-content-option:nth-child(3) > sn-workspace-list-module")
  .shadowRoot.querySelector("div > div.list-wrapper > now-record-list-connected")
  .shadowRoot.querySelector("div > now-record-list")
  .shadowRoot.querySelector("div > div.sn-list-grid-container > div > now-table")
  .shadowRoot.querySelector("#gridcontainer > div > table > tbody")
```

Comment: `I tried to load the selector after the DOM is loaded and even after a timeout of 10 seconds, same result.` This is most likely the problem - you're running the code too early in the page lifecycle, before the DOM has loaded. Where is the code you wrote to execute the script after the page loads?

Comment: if some other script manipulates the DOM elements you want to select, you should wait for window.load instead document.load, check if it works. By the way those elements in the first querySelector are custom elements or you wrote it wrong for not adding the dot or hash before to select classes or IDs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.querySelector("body > sn-workspace-layout > sn-workspace-main > sn-workspace-primary-content > sn-ux-content-option:nth-child(3) > sn-workspace-list-module")
      .shadowRoot.querySelector("div > div.list-wrapper > now-record-list-connected")
      .shadowRoot.querySelector("div > now-record-list")
      .shadowRoot.querySelector("div > div.sn-list-grid-container > div > now-table")
      .shadowRoot.querySelector("#gridcontainer > div > table > tbody")
});
```

This jquery wrapper `$(document).ready()` waits until the pages has loaded.

If this does not work, please provide information what selector does not work specifically and what changes did work for you in the first place.

Comment: Already tried it. The selector that selects now-table doesn't work, it just returns null.